# How to parse out html links from a huge string with html links and other text (Java)

Tags: java, string, parsing, hyperlink, delimiter

my question is how would i be able to go through a string and take out only the links and erase all the rest?  I thought about using some type of delimiter, but wouldn't know how to go about using it in Java.  an example of what i am trying to do:

this is my String:

```
String myString = "The file is http: // www.   .com/hello.txt and the second file is "
                     + "http: // www.   .com/hello2.dat";
```

I would want the output to be:

```
"http: // www.   .com/hello.txt http: // www.   .com/hello2.dat"
```

or each could be added to an array, separately.  I just want some ideas, id like to write the code myself but am having trouble on how to do it.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions, or Regex, is built for this kind of work.
It is like another mini-language to learn. The best book out there some would say is [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

The Javadoc for Pattern and Matcher can only serve as a reference. It completely ignores the subtleties involved in regex.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that its going to take some time until i can to what i set out to do. I will read the book and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to use a regular expression. You'll need to find a good one for matching URLs, and see Java's [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes

Comment: Thank you, I read about those things a few hours ago but wasnt sure if it was important. I'm going to look for some examples of them in action.